Does Sinestro need to recharge his ring?
Members of the Green Lantern Corps periodically need to recharge their power rings in the lantern-shaped batteries- does Sinestro or other members of the Sinestro Corps need to do the same with their power rings?

According to this CBR article:

Yellow Lantern rings have a similar recharge procedure to the Green Lantern rings these days, but originally, it was revealed that Sinestro's ring would absorb the power output from a Green Lantern's. It was a strategy largely used by Guy Gardner during his time with the ring (though less maliciously than Sinestro's use of the ability). This syphoning was adapted during the "Sinestro Corps War" storyline by the Corps' fleet of Manhunters.

The current method apparently involves Yellow Lantern Power Batteries that look like lamps.
